# Unable to open sql connection to database in SQL 2008

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to a database running on my local machine from my web application. I can connect to other databases that I created but not this one that I restored from another server. I can connect to the database using the MS SQL Server Management Console and see the database contents, tables etc. but when I try to open an SQL connection I get the error:

"Cannot open database "[Database Name]" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user '[DOMAIN\USERNAME]'"

I have tried setting the login properties User Mapping to dbo and set database role membership to db_owner. I also tried switching to mixed mode where I created a SQL account which also works in management studio but not in my application. My application code works with other databases so it's not the connection string, must be a permissions problem but I'm not seeing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When bringing over a backup from another server, the login names that exist under `Security\Users` is no longer valid because those logins (even though they are mapped to Windows accounts) are valid only for the server the database was on.

In effect, you will have to *remove and then re-add* the logins.

Comment: While that may be true with the existing logins, I created new logins. And in any case, SQL Management Studio doesn't let you delete the dbo login.